# What are important things to do when moving into a new home?

Tags: preparation

I noticed a question re: important things to do when buying a home. For the curious, see [here](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/9581/what-are-the-most-important-things-to-check-do-after-buying-a-home). However, my wife and I are moving into a *brand-new* home in a couple months so much of the advice doesn't seem applicable (changing locks, labeling circuit breakers, cleaning filters and gutters, changing smoke detector batteries, etc...).

What are the things you'd check/investigate/do immediately after moving into a *brand-new* house?

Comment: This question seems too broad, an entire book could be written that covers this topic. But I think that much of the advice you just noted applies -- change the locks (who knows what contractors had keys?), checking circuit breaker labeling (the labels don't always match reality, even in new construction), checking filters (did they remember to install the furnace filter? Is it full of dust from drywall?), changing smoke detector batteries (do you know when the current batteries were installed? Do you know they were new batteries? Maybe they were old smoke detectors pulled from a model home)

Comment: Isn't the original question just as broad? Yet it wasn't put on hold...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- check your home warranty clauses so you are intimately familiar with them
- ask your neighbors (assuming you have some, and after you give them a bottle of wine as a welcome) if they have had any flood / foundation / insect-pest / neighborhood problems
- check city regulations for parking and other municipal restrictions
- contact Homeowners' Association for rules and meeting times/locations
- purchase and install a fireproof safe to store your deed and other documents
- join the neighborhood watch / militia
- if you have kids, walk to the nearest park and school
- scope out the local pub
- enjoy your new home

Oh, and also change the locks, ensure proper labeling of circuit breakers, clean the gutters, change furnace filters, change smoke detector batteries, etc.

Comment: I agree with Jimmy. You never know what manner of contractors, sub contractors, etc all have keys to your house. Now, I am not saying they are bad people, but how could the keep track of all of those keys?

Answer (score 1):

Two items to add are within the attic.

1. Review the amount of insulation in the attic, and verify that the existing insulation is NOT blocking the soffit vents.
2. Verify that the bathroom exhaust fans do not blow into the attic but out of the roof.